# Match everything besides an empty line or lines containing only whitespaces

Tags: regex

What is the easiest way to match all lines which follow these rules:

1. The line is not empty
2. The line does not only contain whitespace

I've found an expression which only matches empty lines or those, who only contains white spaces, but I am not able to invert it. This is what I have found: `^\s*[\r\n]`.

Is it simply possible to invert regular expressions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `\S` means the line where found is not empty, it also means it contains at least a non-whitespace character. The best thing would be to grep the lines using this regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match non-empty lines, you can use the following regex with multiline mode ON (thanks @Casimir for the character class correction):

```
^[^\S\r\n]*\S.*$
```

The end of line is consumed with `.*` that matches any characters but a newline.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW4iR7/10)

To just check if the line is not whitespace (but not match it), use a simplified version:

```
^[^\S\r\n]*\S
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW4iR7/6)

The `[^\S\r\n]*` matches 0 or more characters other than non-whitespace and carriage return and line feed symbols. The `\S` matches a non-whitespace character.

And by the way, if you code in C#, you do not need a regex to check if a string is whitespace, as there is [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.100).aspx), just split the multiline string with `str.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Comment: In the same way you can use `^[^\S\r\n]*\S`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Yes, for checking if the line is not whitespace, it is enough

Comment: I know the c# way, I need this for using in a database;) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just verify that there is at least one non-whitespace character:

```
^.*\S.*$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/tI2pA9/3)

Explanation:

- From start (`^`) til end (`$`)
- `.*` - any amount of any characters
- `\S` - one non-whitespace character

Comment: Forget the /m, forget the old comment